# Monitoramento de Spool de Impressão

Tags: c#, impressora, wmi

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação que monitore a minha impressora e quando o usuário enviar uma impressão, de qualquer programa que seja, ela captura essa informação, pausa a impressão e abre uma nova janela para que o usuário insira um código. Se o código estiver correto ela continua a impressão. Senão, a impressão é cancelada.

No momento estou tentando apenas fazer com que a aplicação pause a impressão. Consigo que ela monitore o spool e retorne as informações do job enviado. Mas não consigo pausar a impressão (não aparece nenhum erro, só não consigo encontrar a função necessária para isso. Já tentei usar InvokeMethod("Pause") mas apenas aparece que não existe essa opção).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace Listar_Servicos
{
    public partial class frmMonitor : Form
    {
        public frmMonitor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMonitor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventWatch("localhost");
        }

        private ManagementEventWatcher manEWatch;

            public void EventWatch(string host)
            {

                ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + host + @"\root\cimv2");
                oMs.Connect();
                manEWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(oMs, new EventQuery("SELECT * FROM    __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 0.1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'"));
                manEWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(mewPrintJobs_EventArrived);
                manEWatch.Start();
            }

            static void mewPrintJobs_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (PropertyData prop in e.NewEvent.Properties)
                {
                    string val = prop.Value == null ? "null" : prop.Value.ToString();

                }

                ManagementBaseObject printJob = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value;
                string v = "";

                foreach (PropertyData propp in printJob.Properties)
                {

                    string name = propp.Name;
                    string val = propp.Value == null ? "null" : propp.Value.ToString();
                    val += "\n";
                    v += name + ":" + val;

                }
                MessageBox.Show(v);
            }

        private void btnNovoMonitor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmMonitor2 novoMonitor = new frmMonitor2();
            novoMonitor.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode querer usar a WinAPI, segue documentação da API de spool de impressão: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx#print_job_functions

Comment: @MarceloUchimura tudo o que eu achei aí é apenas em C++... O recurso de FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification, que pelas minhas pesquisas seria o mais adequado de usar não consigo encontrar em C# também.

Comment: Não precisa programar em C++ para usar este método `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification()`. O que você tem que ver é o decorator `[DllImport]` do C# e a palavra reservada `extern`: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern . Isto é só um começo!

Comment: @MarceloUchimura me ajudou muito. Quer colocar isso de resposta?

Comment: Não, só de saber que foi útil já me conforta. Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Realmente uma solução para o seu problema seria a utilização do que o Marcelo Uchima  colocou nos comentários.

Porém, esta forma de programação, segundo a própria Microsoft:

> Para manter a segurança de tipos e a segurança, o C# não dá suporte à
>   aritmética de ponteiro por padrão. No entanto, usando a palavra-chave
>   unsafe, você pode definir um contexto não seguro no qual os ponteiros
>   podem ser usados.

Também segundo eles, estas são algumas das características do uso de código não seguro:

> - Em alguns casos, o código não seguro pode aumentar o desempenho de um aplicativo removendo as verificações de limites de matriz.
> - Usar o código não seguro apresenta riscos de segurança e estabilidade.

Dependendo do que você for fazer, apesar dos riscos de segurança, se quiser uma performance maior você pode utilizar este método.

Caso você não tenha grandes problemas de performance, utilizar o monitoramento de eventos mesmo é a melhor opção.

Neste código, você não consegue realizar o Invoke no método pois o seu foreach está buscando as propriedades das informações da query.
Crie apenas um foreach da seguinte forma:

```
foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection)
```

E você será capaz de utilizar o `prntJob.InvokeMethod("Pause", null);` (sintaxe parecida para continuar, alterando apenas de *Pause* para *Resume*).